# SFMC SSL Configuration

Tags: marketing-cloud, sfmc-business-unit

we are trying to configure SSL certificate for our domain. SFMC account Executive is asking "Do you need 1 Configuration or 1 Domain with 2 configs?" what did he mean by that? Can someone make me understand.

Answer (score 2):

This may or may not be what they are referring to but in my experience we've had the option of purchasing 1 domain for use with the cloudpages and links within emails. Then another domain for portfolio content. The portfolio SSL is optional, but you can configure both if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the insight.